# Enlarge centered image in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am slowly getting crazy, that's for sure.

To my problem: I created a table and I'm trying to resize an image within a cell to the full width of the cell itself. For whatever reason, this is not working. I have googled my fingers sweaty with no solution that worked. In theory, they all should have.

Here is the code:

```js
function scrollElmVert(el,num) { // to scroll up use a negative number
  var re=/html$/i;
  while(!re.test(el.tagName) && (1 > el.scrollTop)) el=el.parentNode;
  if(0 < el.scrollTop) el.scrollTop += num;
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
var open = null;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (open == this) {
      open.classList.toggle("active");
      open = null;
    } else {
      if (open != null) {
        open.classList.toggle("active");
      }
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      open = this;
      //Scroll to clicked element
      open.scrollIntoView();
      scrollElmVert(open,-68);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin: -5px;
}

/*Code commented to trouble shoot*/
.bg {
 width: 100%;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 0px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion.active+div {
  display: block
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
  
  

<button class="accordion">
    
<div class="cat_text">
Cat 2 Placeholder
</div>
       
  </button>
<div class="panel">
  
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;text-align:center;position:relative;">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/165x555" style ="width:100%">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
  
</div>






<button class="accordion">
    
<div class="cat_text">
Cat 3 Placeholder
</div>
       
  </button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Cat 3 Content</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">
    
<div class="cat_text">
Cat 4 Placeholder
</div>
       
  </button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Cat 4 Content</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">

<div class="cat_text">
Cat 5 Placeholder
</div>

</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content 5</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position:relative` on the parent `div` and `width:100%` on the image, as demonstrated in the code below.

`position:relative` makes it so that child elements have spacial quantities relative to this element. That is, it ensures that `width:100%` of the child elements refers to the width of the element with `position:relative`.

```css
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;text-align:center; position:relative;">
    <div class="img_enlarge_mobile"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/165x550" style = 'width:100%'></div>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why you need `position` in this simple task?

Comment: I updated the answer to show my full implementation, but it's not working on my end even though it does work when I run it here. Is there a way to wrap the code so it's not effected by any other html elements on the page. I work within a Shopify html editor and might have conflicts with other code snippets.

Comment: There was an img {} set to max-width and max-height of 40% which interfered with the code. Got it taken care of and all works now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `img#largeImage {width: 100%;}` to your CSS.

```css
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
img#largeImage {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;text-align:center;">
    <div class="img_enlarge_mobile"><img id="largeImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/165x550"></div>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand why it is challenging?

**Solution**

You just need to add `width:100%` to your `img` tag.

**OR**

Add this CSS code to your CSS

```
.img_enlarge_mobile img{
    width:100%;
}
```

**After Updated OP's question**

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamm2cd2/1/).

```css
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.img_enlarge_mobile img{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;text-align:center;">
    <div class="img_enlarge_mobile"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/165x550"></div>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated the answer to show my full implementation, but it's not working on my end even though it does work when I run it here. Is there a way to wrap the code so it's not effected by any other html elements on the page. I work within a Shopify html editor and might have conflict with other code snippets.

Comment: @FatTwin I updated my answer and created a fiddle example with your updated code Its Working.

Comment: It still doesn't do it on my end. If there is no way to contain this code from other html snippets on the same page, I will have to dig deeper what might be causing this issue. The other visual difference is that my output displays two columns a row as intended, but I am assuming that of no importance right now

Comment: @FatTwin Its seems like you have another `css` imported that crashed your current code, Make sure that you have updated your whole code exactly like on your end?